# Automated smoke test

Tags: testing, automation, qtp

Hi i am not a testing professional but stuck in one issue :
I need to do a smoke test of an pharmacy based application running on 1000s of linux servers in parallel.
Expectation as below:
We deploy  build to all linux servers.
Now we want to do smoke test on all linux servers in parallel and get the result on our jump off server.

Please suggest what can be the efficient way. Any tool.

Comment: please specify the application type, so we can suggest more presisly, like it is desktop app, web socket app, apis , webs etc etc

Comment: The Application type is Desktop Application